# Display the value of a string which looks like Date Time- JSON parameter

Tags: apex, visualforce, json, datatable, outputtext

I have a JSON string that I get in a response. Example:

```
{"Place":[{"datetime":"2011-03-11 04:46:23","depth":24.4,"lng":142.369,"lat":38.322}]}
```

I get the JSON values in the controller and put it in a list that will be used in VF page:

```
public List<Place> place
```

In VF page I use the  to display the values:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!places}" var="var">
  <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">DateTime</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!var.DateTime}"/>
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">Depth</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!var.depth}"/>  
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">Longitude</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!var.lng}"/>
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">Longitude</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!var.lat}"/>
  </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

I get all the values in the table except for one column i.e. `datetime`. It is of type String in the `Class Place`. I am not sure why this String - `"2011-03-11 04:46:23"` would not appear in the table. Any suggestions?

**Root Cause I found:**

In my `apex Class Place` , I have a variable declared to store datetime-> `String adateTime ;` since I can't use dateTime as variable name as it is reserved.

The JSON result has `"datetime":"2011-03-11 04:46:23"`. Hence the value is null.

Comment: Maybe change the case of your key to match your index in the json?

Comment: P.S. `DateTime` is a reserved keyword, and will not work in future versions. If you can change your JSON, you should do so. Also, JSON parsing is case sensitive, as mentioned by Ronnie.

Comment: Just added the root cause in the question and you commented the same :) . I cannot change the JSON as it is coming from third party. What option do I have here?

Comment: maybe [rename the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391579/how-to-rename-json-key)?

Comment: Yes , I looking at that option. May be I should use - JSONParser class - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_JsonParser.htm#apex_class_System_JsonParser

Comment: @SfdcBat Yes, JSONparser may be your best choice, that or renaming the key, as glls said. I try to avoid JSONParser myself because it tends has a lot of overhead CPU-wise.

Comment: I thought I have to use JSONParser to implement what glls suggested? Because there is no `JSON.parse` in Apex or do I need to look into some other method/class for implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JSON.deserializeUntyped to get at the data. Here's an exec anon example that demonstrates this:

```
String body = '{"Place":[{"datetime":"2011-03-11 04:46:23","depth":24.4,"lng":142.369,"lat":38.322}]}';
Map<String, Object> placeObject = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(Body);
List<Object> placeObjectList = (List<Object>)placeObject.get('Place');
for(Object placeValueItem: placeObjectList) {
    Map<String, Object> placeValue = (Map<String, Object>)placeValueItem;
    System.debug(placeValue.get('datetime'));
    System.debug(placeValue.get('depth'));
    System.debug(placeValue.get('lng'));
    System.debug(placeValue.get('lat'));
}
```

I find that this is marginally easier than dealing with JSONParser, as you get native objects to work with. Note that DateTime values will need to be parsed if you want them as anything other than a string.

Comment: Much simpler. I was going to use JSONParser and recreate the JSON string with expected tags but that looks like lot of processing time.